# How to create a specific layout in html?

Tags: css, layout, html

I would like to create a specific layout in html but have some dificulties.

Images are easier to understand than words, so here is what I have:

[image]

This is fine, but as soon as the div1 gets heigher, I will have this:

[image]

And my goal is to have something like that:

[image]

For the moment, I am using divs, which is probably not the good idea. Any help is welcome.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I have tryed to create 3 divs, which is giving me the 2nd image result. Then I tryed to use a simple <a> tag instead of the 3rd div, and still the same result.

Comment: I mean you can have any type of layout using nested div's.. but it seems you want to change the layout when the height of a div is changed.. is it so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divs are a great way to do it. You can use a floated layout with a containing div around the two right divs. Here is some code to show you what I mean:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="main_content">
        <div id="top_right"></div>
        <div id="bottom_right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper { background: #44BBF0; }
#sidebar { float: left; width: 100px; height: 500px; background: #485F40; }
#main_content { float: right; }
#top_right { width: 200px; height: 200px; background: #FF553F; }
#botom_right { width: 200px; height: 300px; background: #B0DE91; }

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    zoom: 1; /* IE < 8 */
}
```

Here is a JS fiddle link to show you how it looks: http://jsfiddle.net/ddxYB/

Make sure to clear the wrapper div. Because it contains only floated elements, it will have no height if you don't. In the example I used, I set heights to save time, but this would just as well if you used automatic heights and let the divs take on the height of the content.

This is a screenshot from the JSFiddle code:

[image: This is a screenshot from the JSFiddle code]

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: I encountered a problem, could you plese help me. When setting in JSFiddle: `#sidebar { float: left; width: 100px; height: 50px; background: #485F40; }` then the blue div is comming on the lefto of the orange div, and it should be on th ebottom of the orange div.

Comment: @Milos Oops! My mistake, I had a typo in the css! I had accidentally spelled #right_bottom as #right_botom. Here's the fixed jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ddxYB/4/

Comment: thanks again, but this is not exactly what I am looking for. I would like that the "bottom_right" div takes also the "sidebar" space if the sidebar is smaller than the "top-right" div.

Comment: @Milos sounds like this still might not be exactly what you're talking about but hopefully it's closer? This is just the same except without putting the two right side divs in their own containing div: http://jsfiddle.net/ddxYB/5/

Comment: This is actually designed to fail for the first image on the list. There is no way for the blue div to ever move over to the left.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to understand concept of a **container**.

Create 2 containers as columns:

- A left column containing div1
- A right column containing div2 and div3

So for the HTML create a **structure** like this:

```
<div class="col1">
    <div>div 1</div>
</div>

<div class="col2">
    <div>div 2</div>
    <div>div 3</div>
</div>
```

And positioning columns with CSS:

```
div.col1 {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

div.col2 {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: This is nt working to obtain something as described on image 1. The left side of the screen will allways be blank.

Comment: This is not for the final result but to explain the use of a divs container (column). Important step.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry. Do you have any idea on how to reach my goal?

Answer (score -3):

Set your CSS position of each div to absolute and position them using margin.

```
#divName {
position: absolute;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px; //position them wherever you want.
}
```