# HTML divs, how to wrap content?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 div's like on this image:

[image]

div1 has fixed width but variable height, so what I would like is that if div1 height is bigger that the div2 height, the div3 stays under div2 and on the right of the div1, like here:

[image]

Any idea on how to do this? For the moment, I have created a container:

```
<div class="colcontainer">
    <div class="col-left">
    {% block news %}{% endblock %}
    </div>  
    <div id="main_content">
        <div class="col-right">
            {% block rightcol %}{% endblock %}
        </div> 
        <div id="content">
            <div class="contentwrap">
                <div class="itemwrap">
                {% block content %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content-bottom"><div class="content-bottom-left"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS is like this:

```
.col-left {
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width: 300px;
    min-height:198px;
}

.col-right {
    text-align:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 0 0 200px;
}

#content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 980px;
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JRbFy)

Comment: The link to your previous question might be useful for others [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954311/how-to-create-a-specific-layout-in-html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954311/how-to-create-a-specific-layout-in-html)

Comment: @Milos Can you please explain how the height of div1 will be changed?

Comment: @Mr_Green, In fact, the div1 has min height defined by css, but if there are some more data in the div, the dif height will be automaticaly increased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As CSS doesn't provide anything for that job yet, you will have to use Javascript.

I would firstly create a page like on your first picture.
Then I would use

```
$("#div").height()
```

, which returns the height of your div and compare this to your second div's height:

```
if($("#div1").height() > $("div2").height())
  //change website...
```

In the if body put the required css changes... That should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you @ltsstar, but are you sure that there is no CSS / HTML solution for that?

Comment: Firstly. This does not achieve a third area which floats to the right of the first when the content of the 2nd is shorter so fails the first image.

Secondly. I can't believe you went to all that effort for a two column layout!!

Answer (score 6):

Atlast, I got it :)  Just wrap all those three elements in a parent element as shown below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="div1"></div>  <!-- Change height to see result -->
   <div class="div2"></div>
   <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main{width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid black;overflow:hidden;}
.div1{width:100px;min-height:100px;float:left;background-color:green;}
.div2{width:100px;display:inline-block;height:100px;background-color:blue;}
.div3{width:100px;display:inline-block;height:100px;background-color:red;margin-top:-4px;}
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ujwb6/4/)

If you want to have the width of the third div to be wide from before itself then I highly recommend you to go with jQuery.

```
.div3{width:200px;}  /* Keeping width wide enough with the container */
```

---

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    if($('.div1').height() > 100)
       $('.div3').width(100)
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ujwb6/3/)

Comment: @Milos Well, I have given you a demo which can demonstrate how close I was with only css. Please try on that demo to get your result. I am sure that I am missing some silly stuff to use in css.

Comment: I've been trying since this question was made.  I can not get it with pure CSS.  Maybe with the assistance of something like SASS but this is impossible with nothing but standard CSS3.  My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n8N59/

Comment: My lord there seems to be a lot of people trying to use js here. Js is not always available. JS is never the way to deal with this situation!

Answer (score 4):

If you style the `#content` like this it works.

```
#content {
    background: #fbb;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Notice there is no float.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JRbFy/1/

jsFiddle with equal height left-column and content effect: http://jsfiddle.net/JRbFy/2/

Comment: Seems to work fine on JSFiddle, I have to test this on my project. Thank you very much

Comment: Updated with an equal height `#content` and `.col-left` version too. :)

Answer (score 2):

If i understood properly you want something like this?

```
<style>
    #container1
    {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #left
    {
        width: 30%;
        background: #123456;
        float: left;
        height: 50%;
    }
    #right
    {
        width: 70%;
        float: left;
        height: 50%;
    }
    #right_top
    {
        background: #111111;
        height: 30%;
    }
    #right_bottom
    {
        background: #777777;
        height: 70%;
    }
</style>

<div id="container1">
    <div id="left">Div 1</div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="right_top">Div 2</div>
        <div id="right_bottom">Div 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you, at least pointing you in the right direction.

CSS:

```
.box {border:1px dashed black;}
#content {width:1000px;}
#clear {clear:both;}

#left {float:left; width:200px; height:100px; margin-right:15px;}
#top {float:left; width:780px; height:200px;}
#main {float:left; min-width:780px; max-width:1000px;}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="box" id="content">
<div class="box" id="left">Left</div>
<div class="box" id="top">Top</div>
<div class="box" id="main">Main</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

And finally my solution comes too :)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JRbFy/3/

Just using `margin: 10px auto;` , and taking the `content div` out of the `main_content div`:

HTML

```
<div class="colcontainer">
    <div class="col-left">
    {% block news %}{% endblock %}
        <br/>
        <b>Hover on me to increase my height </b>
    </div>  
    <div id="main_content">
        <div class="col-right">
            {% block rightcol %}{% endblock %}
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="contentwrap">
            <div class="itemwrap">
                {% block content %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="content-bottom"><div class="content-bottom-left"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.colcontainer{
    width: auto;
}

.col-left {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 silver;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width: 300px;
    min-height:198px;
}

.col-left:hover{    
    height: 300px;
}

.col-right {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 steelblue;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 0 0 200px;
    height:198px;
}

#content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 yellowgreen;    
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as everyone luuuuuuurves jQuery, I decided to throw something together that actually does what you asked. Have fun :)

```
<div id="div1">
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
<div id="div3">
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
<div id="div4">
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Throw in some css

```
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4 {
    border:3px double #000;
    background:#fff
}
#div1 {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}
#div4 {
    clear:both;
}
```

And finally your jQuery.

```
$(function () {
    $('#div2').css({
        marginLeft: $('#div1').outerWidth()
    });
    if ($('#div2').height() < $('#div1').height()) {
        $('#div3').css({
            marginLeft: $('#div1').outerWidth()
        });
    }
});
```

Now. I am not advocating this method, just saying that it actually achieved what you asked for whereas nothing else here has ;)

See it at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fm67v/). Simply add one more <p>Test</p> to div1 and you will see that div3 then goes to the right of div1 as per your image.

Now, I know someone will say "But div1 doesn't take all the height then!", well fear not. Check the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fm67v/1/) with one added piece to the javascript to see your questions answered too. Just delete one of the <p>Test</p> from div1.

```
$(function () {
    $('#div2').css({
        marginLeft: $('#div1').outerWidth()
    });
    if ($('#div2').height() < $('#div1').height()) {
        $('#div3').css({
            marginLeft: $('#div1').outerWidth()
        });
        $('#div1').css({
            height: $('#div2').outerHeight() + $('#div3').height()
        });
    }
});
```

I have to reiterate that this solution relies on Javascript. Turn it off, device doesnt support it, this stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily answers the question, but I thought you might like to know that in CSS 3 you can use this style - {word-wrap: break-word;} - to fit a long string inside a div.

Answer (score 0):

I probably missed read the question but does this not have have the desired layout you wanted.

https://jsfiddle.net/94ohw4hq/

```
<div id="container">
<div class="left">
Left
</div>
<div class="right">
Right
</div>
<div class="bottom">
Bottom
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Use

> wookmark plugin

to solve your problem