# How to make text wrap?

Tags: css

Right now my text looks like this, going outside the container.
How do I make it stay inside the container and break into seperate lines?

[image: Image of what the code produced before I fixed it.]

```
<div class="container Me" style="display: block;">
  <img src="images/me.jpg" alt="Me">
  <div class="content">
    <p class="name">Me</p>
    <p>hello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello worldhello world</p>
    <i class="material-icons reply">reply</i>
    <span class="time">4:46</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have with us?

Comment: What container?

Comment: The `<div>` that the `<p>` is inside of.

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962459/html-divs-how-to-wrap-content

Comment: CSS: word-wrap: break-word;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the word-wrap property in css:

```
p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```